# end anchors with double second bracket

Tags: regex

I want data that only matches the passengerData. I tried like below but it's not working properly

```
$getContent='passenger list: 

"passengerData":{"id-1":{...},"id-2":{...},...."id-nth":{...}};

flight List:

"flightData":{"id-1":{...},"id-2":{...},...."id-nth":{...}};';

preg_match_all('/"passengerData([^*]+\}})/', $getContent, $matches);
```

Comment: Try this: `/"passengerData":([^;]+}})/`

Comment: Or another option `"passengerData"\h*:\h*\K{.*?}};` https://regex101.com/r/q5YZJ7/1

Comment: If you can change whatever *produced* this data to write pure JSON (or some other well-defined standard format) you won't need to fool around with error-prone, write-only regex solutions. This is basically isomorphic to the old "don't use regex for HTML" FAQ.

Comment: Happy my answer worked for you. Please also kindly upvote my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
/"passengerData"\s*:\s*({.*?}});$/m
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/q5YZJ7/2). `$matches[1]` must have the data you want.

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "passengerData"          '"passengerData"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }}                       '}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```